# getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection & getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACpEQ.png)

please when I select from my dropdown it displays the following error: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection & getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection problem on flutter

Comment: Hi! Please post your question in English so everybody can understand and try to help you. Also double check your question for proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me as well because of another function running in background of same context. But if it doesn't gives you an error then that's ok(as in my case).

But if it gives error you just check if two or more function or build running simultaneously.

OR

Share the full code here (your code has only a portion of it)so we can check it.